# How to test claims-config.xml file WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

WSO2 documentation states that claims are read from the claim-config.xml file only once here: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Adding+Claim+Mapping

```
"The claims configured in <IS_HOME>/repository/conf/claim-config.xml file get 
applied only when you start the product for the first time, or for any newly 
created tenants. With the first startup, claim dialects and claims will be 
loaded from the file and persisted in the database. Any consecutive updates to 
the file will not be picked up and claim dialects and claims will be loaded 
from the database."
```

The documentation makes it seem like you only have "one chance" to see how your claim-config.xml works.  I'm in the process of developing and debugging the file though - is there a way to force WSO2 to read from the claim-config.xml file again or delete relevant data from the database to force claim-config.xml to be read?

I'd like to avoid completely uninstalling the product and reinstalling every time I want to observe a change I made to the claim-config.xml file.

Things I have tried:

1. Completely deleting the database files (WSO2CARBON_DB.h2.db) from `\repository\database`.  This prevented the WSO2 server from starting up.
2. Deleting the entries from the IDN_CLAIM table from the H2 database.  This started the server, but I wasn't able to login.

Comment: Any specific reason to force WSO2 to read from the claim-config.xml file?. If you want to add/delete claim rather than editing the claim-config.xml file, you could add/edit/delete claims through UI as mentioned in the above documentation

Comment: I'm interested in making things as automated as possible.  Utilizing the configuration file maximizes the portability of my solution.

Comment: After deleting the WSO2CARBON_DB.h2.db, you need to start the server with '-Dsetup' flag. Note: Removing it will remove all data rather than users data.

Answer (score 0):

> Completely deleting the database files (WSO2CARBON_DB.h2.db) from
>   \repository\database. This prevented the WSO2 server from starting up.

If you are okay with completely resetting databases, you can delete above files. As @senthalan wrote in comments, then you need to start the server with '-Dsetup' flag. It recreates DB, re-populates the configuration and starts the server.

```
sh wso2server.sh -Dsetup
```